# How can i fit 2 commands in 1 terminal shortcut

Tags: mount, directory, command-line

10 latest updates and drivers and I need to run a game called unreal tournament, but in terminal it requires 2 commands
The first one is to mount into the folder:

```
cd /usr/local/games/ut2004/
```

and then the second one is to open the actual game:

```
sudo aoss ./ut2004
```

In one shortcut i can only fit 1 command but both don't fit in
is there any way i can turn these 2 commands into one? Perhaps turni9ng on the desktop shortcut already mounted into the folder?
Any help would be really appreciated because im getting kinda sick of using the terminal to run it every time.

Comment: Do you need to run the game with `sudo`? Running a game as root is bad security practice.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`cd /usr/local/games/ut2004/ && sudo aoss ./ut2004`

Comment: Using `&&` instead of my proposed `;` is a good practise.

Comment: @jippie - mind saying why?

Comment: Because ; would not check if the first command returned a success. CommandA && commandB || commandC basically means 'do command A and, if successful, do command B, otherwise do command C'

Comment: I agree with LoremIpsum. If the `cd /usr/local/games/ut2004` fails, it produces an error and the next command (`sudo aos ./ut2004`) is not executed. To troubleshoot in case of an issue only one error is produced and therefore it is easier to solve.

Answer (score 4):

Either you enter: `cd /usr/local/games/ut2004/; sudo aoss ./ut2004`, thus with the extra ; in between ...

... or you create a small shell script in your home directory:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /usr/local/games/ut2004/
sudo aoss ./ut2004
```

and call that from your shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a 'shortcut' you can create a bash function. Add this to your ~/.bashrc file:

```
function play {
cd /usr/local/games/ut2004/ && sudo aoss ./ut2004
}
```

Once you save ~/.bashrc run: **source ~/.bashrc**

(You only have to do that once.)

Now just type this in a terminal:

```
$ > play
```

...and hit enter

Comment: `play` is a bad choice for a command name as it is commonly used to play music files. `/usr/bin/play` is part of the sox package.

Comment: @jippie good call

Answer (score 0):

```
/bin/sh -c "cd /usr/local/games/ut2004/ && sudo aoss ./ut2004"
```

Note that cd, && and ; are shell built-in operators and will not work in a .desktop shortcut as the command line is directly executed as-is, so you must call a shell to interpret them.

Answer (score 0):

You could also create an alias in your .bach_aliases file like 'alias unreal='cd /usr/local/games/ut2004/ && sudo aoss ./ut2004'. That way the next time you login you just type unreal and start playing.